# How to set variable in Script Task when Value is an Array in Camunda

Tags: javascript, bpmn, camunda, nashorn, camunda-modeler

I am trying to merge two array into one array of Object and Set this Object as Variable for further use.
Using Script Format “javascript” and script type “Inline script”.

below is the code that I was trying.

```
var A_Group = execution.getVariableTyped("A_Group", true).getValue()
var B_Group = execution.getVariableTyped("B_Group", true).getValue()
var groupList = new Array
for(var i=0; i<A_Group.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<B_Group.length;j++){
       groupList.push({ 
        "A_Group"  : A_Group[i],
        "B_Group"  : B_Group[j]
    });
    }
}
execution.setVariable("GroupList", groupList);
```

But whenever flow reached this script it shows this error

*500 Internal Server Error*

```
{
    "type": "RestException",
    "message": "Cannot instantiate process definition Process_11qsgp3:3:0c411f07-4944-11eb-9f3b-5c80b61f42fc: 
    Cannot serialize object in variable 'GroupList': SPIN/DOM-XML-01030 Cannot create context"
}
```

Please, any lead will be helpful. Ask in comment if not clear.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Did you see https://forum.camunda.org/t/error-while-parsing-json-output-spin-dom-xml-01009/7976 ?
There likely is an issue with the data you are sending in.

You may also want to consider using the JS method **concat** instead
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Also:

> All process variables that are accessible through the execution that
> arrives in the Script Task can be used within the script.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/tasks/script-task/